# How to connect to Wifi network programatically on Android 10 and above?

Tags: kotlin, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

```
val ssid = "Your WiFi SSID"
val password = "Your WiFi password"
val networkSSID = "\"$ssid\""
val networkPassword = "\"$password\""
val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
wifiConfiguration.SSID = networkSSID
wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = networkPassword
val networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration)
wifiManager.disconnect()
wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)
wifiManager.reconnect()
```

Used this code but it is not working on Android 10 and above.Also followed https://github.com/ThanosFisherman/WifiUtils but which also not working on Android 10 and above. Can some one suggest how to connect to wifi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try ConnectivityManager and NetworkCallbacks to do this task like this way:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun connectToWiFi(pin: String, ssid:String) {
    val connectivityManager =
         context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as 
         ConnectivityManager
    val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
        .setSsid(ssid)
        .setWpa2Passphrase(pin)
        .setSsidPattern(PatternMatcher(ssid, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX))
        .build()
    val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
        .build()
    val networkCallback = object : NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
          showToast(context,context.getString(R.string.connection_success))
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable()
            showToast(context,context.getString(R.string.connection_fail))
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            showToast(context,context.getString(R.string.out_of_range))
        }
    }
  connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zahid Muneer thank you so much you made my day this code working perfectly. Can i know how to disconnect from the network once after connected.

Comment: private fun disconnectFromWiFi(network: Network) {
    val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.networkId == network.netId) {
        wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifiInfo.networkId)
        wifiManager.disconnect()
    }
}
you can try this function whenever you want to disconnect. Before calling this just save the network object in a variable that that we are receiving in onAvailable() method and pass it to this function as parameter.

Comment: I could connect to the specified wifi network, but there was no Internet. 
If I connect from the Settings, Internet works fine
@ZahidMuneer have encounter such error?

Comment: Faced the same error as described by @Vlad There was no Internet when connecting using the above code. If I connect from Settings, then the Internet works fine.

Comment: "connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)"  you can call this method inside onAvailable callback

Comment: this requires WRITE_SETTINGS permission